# An array item value taken from input's v-model

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am creating a dropdown menu where the user is able to check multiple checkboxes and the values will be added to the array and after that displayed in DOM.

But the user must be able to write his own option in the input and this value will be also added to the array and afterward displayed in DOM with the other options.

The "other" input should be hidden until the "other" checkbox is checked.

my idea was to add `: value` attribute which will be reflecting input's v-model value but it does not work the way I want.

Any ideas, please? Thank you for all your tips.

I made an example - in JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/rxz65s4m/4/

Code:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h1>
    What have you eaten today?
  </h1>

  <input type="checkbox" id="first" v-model="selected" value="Fish">
  <label for="first">Fish</label>
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" id="second" v-model="selected" value="Meat">
  <label for="second">Meat</label>
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" id="third" v-model="selected" value="Potatoes">
  <label for="third">Potatoes</label>
  <br />

  <!-- Need to take the value from the input -->
  <input type="checkbox" id="fourth" v-model="selected" :value="otherText">
  <label for="fourth">Other</label>
  <!-- this input should be hidden until the checkbox above is checked -->
  <input type="text" v-model="otherText">

  <p>
    {{selected}}
  </p>
</div>
```

and script:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selected: [],
    otherText: null
  }
})
```

**EDIT:** For better explanation: After the "other" checkbox is checked, user will be able to type inside the input which is located right next to the "other" checkbox. The word which is typed inside the input should be added to the array which is then displayed in DOM. Typing in the input should reactively change the value in array so in the end there should be e.g. array: ["Fish", "somethingUserTyped"]

Comment: The `otherText` input is working as expected, what is your desired behavior?

Comment: @Slim thank you for your comment. I added EDIT for the better explanation.

Comment: Slim sorry dear, I was pointing to @MapeSVK

Answer (score -2):

You can use the `@change` event.

Compare: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mgLrv4kd/1/

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selected: [],
    otherText: null
  },
  methods: {
    getInput(input) {
      this.selected.push(input);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
 <input type="text" v-model="otherText" @change="getInput(otherText)">
```